# Asymptotes of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the function $f(x) = x\cdot \arctan(x)$ 
And i need to find all asymptotes, I am stuck at $\lim_{x\to \infty}x\cdot \arctan(x)$, please help me.

Comment: Have you tried graphing the function? It can often give you an idea on how to approach this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no horizontal asymptotes because the limits at infinity do not exist (they're both positive infinities):

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}x\arctan{x}=+\infty.$$

What about the so-called oblique asymptotes? Judging by the way the graph looks, it seems like the function might have two of them. Here's how you can find them:

$$
a=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x\arctan{x}}{x}=
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}{\arctan{x}}=\pm\frac{\pi}{2},
$$
$$
b=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(f(x)-ax)=
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\left(x\arctan{x}\pm\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)=
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{\arctan{x}\pm\frac{\pi}{2}}{1/x}.
$$

Now, to find that limit, you have to use L'Hôpital's rule on it. When you're finally done (and if the limit exists), plug the values of $a$ and $b$ that you've found (there are going to be two pairs of them) into this simple linear equation:

$$y=ax+b.$$

That's going to give you the equations of your two oblique asymptotes.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

If you consider that 
$$\arctan (x) + \arctan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ then, for large values of $x$, using Taylor series
$$\arctan (x)= \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3x^3} +\ldots $$ which makes
$$x \arctan (x)=-1+\frac{\pi}{2}x+\frac{1}{3x^2} +\ldots$$

Then ???

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to \infty}\arctan(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ as $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \infty$. Then this is multiplied by $x$ so the limit is infinity.